# Difference between bash (shell) function syntaxes?

Tags: bash, function, shell, syntax

I just realized I've seen multiple function syntaxes in bash (or maybe they were different shell languages?) scripts. Namely:

```
function my_function()
{
}

function my_function
{
}

my_function()
{
}
```

Is there any difference between them? Is any of them incorrect or preferred?

Comment: Without `function` is typically preferred as it is more portable. The function keyword can stop the function name from clashing with previously declared aliases though.

Comment: `function` was borrowed from `ksh`, where it could have a slight affect on the function definition. Its inclusion in `bash` was probably to make people switching from `ksh` more comfortable and to ease porting scripts.

Comment: And do the parentheses have any purpose?

Comment: In the POSIX syntax, they are what actually signal a function definition. With `function`, they are redundant.